# Module not found webpack-dev-server

Tags: angular

I have a error when i start my project even if i create new project by ng new AppName and i run my project with ng serve after that and it still have that error. Help me (Angular)

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\AD\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\PaymentPj\PaymentApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%2C%22runtimeErrors%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\AD\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\PaymentPj\PaymentApp'

I try to delete node-module and reinstall by npm i but my project still not work

Update: I moved my project to new folder without special character and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to the path where your Angular project resides. Specifically, the issue might be the `#` character in the `C#` directory of the path `C:\Users\AD\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\PaymentPj\PaymentApp`.

Special characters like `#` can cause issues with some tools and scripts. The `#` character has a special meaning in URLs (it's used for fragments). This is likely confusing Webpack or the Angular CLI when it tries to resolve module paths.

To fix this error, try the following steps:

1. **Move Your Project**:

   - Move your project out of the `C#\` directory to a directory without special characters. For example: `C:\Users\AD\OneDrive\Desktop\PaymentPj\PaymentApp`.
2. **Reinstall the Modules**:

   - Navigate to the new project directory using your terminal or command prompt.
   - Delete the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file.
   - Run `npm install` to reinstall the dependencies.
3. **Serve the Application**:

   - Once the dependencies are reinstalled, try running `ng serve` again.

The error should be resolved after moving the project to a path without special characters and reinstalling the dependencies.